# How to add a text field to views exposed filter results?

Tags: 7, ajax, views

I have a view that shows prices for different activities.

Each price is a content type called Activity. On the content type, they choose the activity from a select list, enter the price and save. The view then groups the price packages by their activity, and there is an exposed filter to show them with ajax.

I now want to add specific price and booking information to display in the footer of the view for each activity. This text needs to be able to be changed by my client.

What im struggling with is where I put the text fields for the client to fill in, and how i reference these in the view.

**What ive tried...**

1. I tried adding field collection items to the page they are displayed on, so my client can edit that page, and add a field collection item for each activity. Then i show those results in an embedded view inside the footer of the original view, telling it to inherit contextual filters, but that just shows all of the results.
2. I also tried adding a new content type using the same activity select list field, with a body field for them to add. But the same happens as above, the attaced view just shows all results, and pays no attention to the exposed filter from the main view.

Can anyone help?

Comment: An image or sketch to show the desired end result might help. But based on my understanding, I think you can do the following:
1. Create a new content type called: "activity information" for example.
2. Using "Entity Reference" module, you can add a reference field to "Activity" content type so when a new activity is created, you can select the associated information (i.e. a node of type "Activity information").
3. In the view, you can query Activities and use something like "Entity Reference View Widget" module to show the related info. Check Entity Reference View Widget documentation.

Comment: do you mean the footer of each group, or the footer of the entire View?

Comment: The footer of the entire view, but only one group is shown at each time (Depending on which exposed filter the user selects) and the text should be different at the bottom for each result.